# Making my boxes responsive in css

Tags: css

I have 8 boxes on my html file, when viewing on the desktop, everything looks OK, visited on the mobile and the colums are way off than it should be, it should be in the center, not in the right side, how would i do that to make it responsive? 
[Preview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w0EEh.png)

My code for the columns.

```
.articles {
    margin: 100px;
    background-color: #F5F5F5;
    }

 .article {
    margin: 5px;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 340px;
    position: relative;
    float:left;
    left: 155px;
    box-shadow: 0 2px 16px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12);
  }

  .article-image {
    width: 100%;
  }
  .article-text-wrapper {
    padding: 20px;
  }

  .article-title {
    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
    font-size: 20px;
    font-weight: 700;
  }
 .article-description {
    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
    line-height: 16px; 
    font-size: 16px;
    color: rgba(0,0,0,0.7);
    font-weight: 300;
  }

  .article-time {
    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
    font-size: 12px;
    color: rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
    font-weight: 300;
  }
```

Thanks alot.

Comment: can you also add an example of your html structure?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have `left` and `margin` properties applied to your `article` elements. You will need to add a `media` query for the following:

```
@media only screen and (max-width:700px) {
   .articles {
    margin: 50px 0;
   }
   .article {
    left: 0;
    width:100%;
   }
}
```

Comment: That works, mobile view looks perfect. The desktop view is now messed up, any workaround about this?

Comment: Did you add the code as a media query or did you change your existing code?

Comment: @Andrewyed this should not affect your desktop view. The media query only fires for screen sizes less than 700px

Comment: @Andrewyed if you added this code as I’ve written it, it should have absolutely no effect on your desktop view. Did you change something else?

Comment: Sorry about that, inserted the code to wrong place, fixed now. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your article has fixed width, float and is displayed as inline-block. 
Try by adding the following media query:

```
@media only screen  and (max-width : 768px) {

 .article {
    margin: 0 auto;
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 340px;
    float: none;
    left: auto;
  }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

When making responsive web pages, add the following  element in all your web pages:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
```

Set CSS width property is set to 100% for images, the image will be responsive and scale up and down. And also use max-width property.

For better responsive design use **Media Queries**.

```
@media screen and (max-width: 800px) {
  .class-name {
    width: 100%; /* The width is 100%, when the viewport is 800px or smaller */
  }
}
```

[Refer here](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_responsive.asp)